# Why does this C stringification macro corrupt whilst expanding?

Tags: c, macros, stringify

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define QUOTE(str) #str
#define EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(str) QUOTE(str)
#define TEST one-of-a-linux

int main() {
  printf(EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(TEST)"\n");
}
```

I get:

one-of-a-1

rather than

one-of-a-linux

Note that "linux" becomes "1" - i.e. the digit one

Comment: It means `linux` is a macro evaluating to `1`.

Comment: If you are using gcc you might want to try `-std=c89` or `-std=c99` to avoid this issue.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: third party curiosity, why would that help?

Comment: gcc predefines a lot of userspace macros like `linux` and `unix` unless you put it in a stricter standards-compliant mode.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: `-std=c99` was exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Linux box:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep 'linux\|unix'
#define __unix__ 1
#define __linux 1
#define __unix 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define unix 1
#define linux 1
$
```

Note the value of `unix` being 1 on unix platforms has been used in an IOCCC entry. Winner of the "Best One Liner" in 1987.

http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#1987_korn

The code was:

```
    main() { printf(&unix["\021%six\012\0"],(unix)["have"]+"fun"-0x60);}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's obviously `#define linux 1` somewhere (or `-Dlinux=1`).

Answer (score 1):

```
#undef linux
#define TEST one-of-a-linux
```

Comment: One may not want to do that in a general case, in case any other system headers (that might use `linux`) are included after that.

Comment: `undef linux` can be followed by `#define linux linux`

Comment: @DanFego: Not if it's followed by main like in the example given. Generally you wouldn't do this in a header anyway...

Comment: @ugoren: Yes it can. Don't do that.

Comment: @matt, I think it should have been `#define linux linux` in the first place. It lets you ask `#ifdef linux`, but does nothing more. But changing what the compiler defined, even if you improve it, is indeed not something you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `#define` for `linux` to `1` somewhere in your code. The following works fine!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#undef linux

#define QUOTE(str) #str
#define EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(str) QUOTE(str)
#define TEST one-of-a-linux

int main(void) 
{
    printf(EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(TEST)"\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
/*
$ gcc mm.c 
$ ./a.out 
one-of-a-linux
$ 
*/
```

Note:

```
#define TEST 1linux
#define TEST linux1
```

prints the expected answers appropriately!